# Wordpress site is not updating

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I update something in my website whether it's on pages, posts, categories, menus, or more then it's not showing the changed result on the site when I open the website from google search or incognito. But it shows the changes when I access it from the dashboard.

More, I already have cleared the server cache, browser cache, website cache as well as Cloudflare cache but still not working.

So, can anyone help me out to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cache-related issue. If you have used any caching plugin (WP-Rocket, W3 total cache, LiteSpeed, etc), you have to clear the cache from that plugin. You can use VPN & try a different browser to get the latest updates.
You can check instant results from different servers here:

[Proxy Site](https://www.proxysite.com/)